# Simulate human mouse movement using xdotool

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux

I'm currently using bash and xdotool to write a simple script which will hold down a few keys and, at the same time, move the mouse relative to the current pointer position. Everything works, except I dislike the choppiness the instant mouse movement from xdotool provides. Is there any way to make xdotool move the mouse over a period of time or a curve? Or even a flag to "smoothen" the mouse that I missed? Any help is appreciated. My current code is pasted below.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "This script requires xdotool to work. Please install it if you haven't already.\n"
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue"
printf "...\n"
printf "Process will begin in 5 seconds.\n"
printf "Press Ctrl+C at any time to halt the script\n"
sleep 5
xdotool mousedown 1
xdotool keydown w
xdotool keydown k
end=$((SECONDS+1300))
while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]; do
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync 0 50
xdotool mousemove_relative --sync -- 0 -50
:
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so there isn't anything in xdotool that can do this. *However,* there exists a [tool](https://github.com/xvol/bezmouse) written in python that simulates human mouse movement using Bézier curves. It does almost exactly what I want and works pretty well with bash (and python if you're into that). Wonderful tool for this purpose, hope this helps someone.